# Mysql Replace text contained between two patterns

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress, replace

I want to change a shortcode on the wordpress wp_posts table. On the post_contents field, I have some html code with few shortcodes like this:

```
[PFltr "this text is variable, changes on each occurrence"]
```

I want to change for this:

```
[scode option="1"]this text is variable changes on each occurrence[/scode]
```

Are there any mysql update query, maybe using regex, for doing this?

Comment: You mean this http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged as [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and [replace](/questions/tagged/replace), you can use

`/\[PFltr\s"([^"]+)"]/` and replace with `[scode option="1"]$1[/scode]`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/vN7sX1/2)

Answer (score 0):

This code will do your thing:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'update_my_content_shortcodes');
function update_my_content_shortcodes() {
    global $wpdb;
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT ID, post_content
         FROM $wpdb->posts
         WHERE post_content LIKE '%[PFltr%'
    "); 

    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        $updated_content = preg_replace('~\[PFltr\s*\"([^\"]*)\"\]~', '[scode option="1"]$1[/scode]', $p->post_content);
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $p->ID,
            'post_content' => $updated_content
        ));
    }
}
```

It will execute once you open your WordPress in the frontend.
Please, note that it will execute on each page load, so you might want to only execute it once, or execute it on certain conditions.